# How to discard unsaved changes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I just wanted to discard all the unsaved changes I'd make to a file in Visual Studio 2022 so I went looking for a `File | Revert` command on the menu but it seems there isn't one.

Is there any way to discard all unsaved changes to a file in Visual Studio without closing the file, choosing not to save, and re-opening it?